# Capitalization. How do "-based" suffix behave when used on titles?

Tags: capitalization, titles, academia, academic-writing

I'm writing an academic article title, and, for matter of capitalizations, I would like to know:

- if "-based" is appended to a word, is "-based" treated as another word and should be written with capitalized "B", or is "-based" treated like a suffix that became one with the word, and thus is written with a non-capitalized "b"?

Title example:

- "**Computer-Based** Strategies For Asking About Title Capitalization On Stack Exchange";
- "**Computer-based** Strategies For Asking About Title Capitalization On Stack Exchange".